# How to install a SSL certificate from CAcert.org into GlassFish v3

Tags: ssl, glassfish

I am trying to enable ssl on my internet glassfish server using my own CAcert.org certificate. I followed the introduction from Masoud Kalali :
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kalali/archive/2010/02/27/how-install-godaddy-certificate-your-glassfish-v3

But after all when I try to connect to my ssl port I got the server error message posted below.
Can anybody help me please what the message "SSL configuration is invalid due to No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled." means?. Could it be possible that a certificate created with CAcert.org is not accapteble for glassfish?

```
   [#|2012-03-20T16:21:00.289+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|GRIZZLY0007: SSL support could not be configured!
java.io.IOException: SSL configuration is invalid due to No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:455)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.init(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:183)
at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.initializeSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:361)
at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.configureSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:237)
at com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps$LazySSLInitializationFilter.execute(GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps.java:202)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.checkEnabledSuites(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:310)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:255)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:451)
... 14 more
|#]
[#|2012-03-20T16:21:00.303+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:352)
at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.obtainSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:399)
at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.execute(SSLReadFilter.java:159)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]
[#|2012-03-20T16:21:00.303+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:352)
at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.obtainSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:399)
at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.execute(SSLReadFilter.java:159)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

|#]
```

Thanks for any help

Ralph

Comment: The blog link is broken, please fix it, so we know what you did.

Comment: I have fixed the broken link: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kalali/archive/2010/02/27/how-install-godaddy-certificate-your-glassfish-v3

Comment: Things to check: keystore in network config is equal to keystore in jvm options, certificate alias, password for keystore equals gf master password. Did you select any cipher suites or do you use all (the default)?

Comment: I have not select any cipher suites, so glassfish should use all. I first created a csr file with openssl. As this did not work I created a new one with the keytool. But all results in the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

at the end of all instructions provided by blog link you wil have smth.jks.

`keytool -list -keystore smth.jks` will list your cetificate as PrivateEntryKey
There is another PrivateEntryKey : `s1as` in original `/domain/domain1/config/keystore.jks`

I guess `s1as` is used by glassfish and when it is not here the server does not start.

S0, you have to include `s1as` and your signed certiface both to original `keystore.jks` as PrivateEntryKey.
But it is not possible to import them separately. If you will try to export PrvateEntryKey from smth.jks, delete it and reimport it then you will found it as trusted certificate. The reason to issue is keytoll can export only self signed part of PrivateEntryKey.

You have to import smth.jks to keytore.jks at once.

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore smth.jks -destkeystore keystore.jks`
also if your smth.jks keystore password is not "changeit" then you have to change master passwrd on glassfish
`keytool -keypasswd -alias s1as -keypass changeit -new 12345678 -keystore keystore.jks`
then `asadmin change-master-password --savemasterpassword=true`

by taking into account the above mentioned I succesfully configured SSL in glassfish 2.1

hope it will help you too